# How to override files when creating a jar in gradle

Tags: java, jar, build, gradle

We have a java project where we have some default configurations under src/main/resources and there are overwrites under project_root/configDeploy

For our mapred jars we want to copy both configs but allow config/deploy files to overwrite defaults in resources. So we can have myconf.xml in resource and myconf.xml in deploy, but the mapred fat jar generated only has myconf.xml

I have tried two different methods, try to have deploy copy and overwrite the resources conf:

```
from 'src/main/resources'
from 'conf/deploy'
```

but this will add two files inside the jar, so it didn't work

Then I tried to add only files from src/main/resources that are not in conf/deploy, something like:

```
into('conf'){
    from{
        'src/main/resources'
    }
    exclude{file('deploy/conf/')}
}
into('conf'){
   from{
       'deploy/conf'
   }
}
```

but this didn't work, as a result none of the confs from resources were copies.
So question is if I have a two folders with files which some of them have same name how can I include their files in jar so I get files from both folders but for files that are in both I get only the version in second folder.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the duplicate files in the JAR you can set the duplicates strategy  to `EXCLUDE` on the task.

```
duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
```

This will cause subsequent attempts to add the file to be ignored. Therefore, if you want files in 'deploy/conf' to take precedence you should define that copy spec first.